# Character array and string terminating character in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, printf

I know that in C, `\0` terminates string.
We can assign both strings and character array to the character array?

```
char c1[] = "hello";
char c2[] = {'h','e','l','l','o'};
```

However, I realize that character array does not have `\0` as terminating character:

```
printf("%d\n",sizeof(c1));  //6
printf("%d\n",sizeof(c2));  //5
```

However when I print them I see something like this:

```
printf("%s\n",c1); //hello
printf("%s\n",c2); //helloV
```

Q1. If I rerun it, second line sometimes print `helloU`, sometimes it prints `helloV`. Why is this so?

Q2. Also how it is ok that character array can contain `\0` terminating string as well as no `\0` terminating character array?

Q3. I know `printf` terminates when it encounters `\0`. How `printf` behaves when it does not encounter `\0`?

[Code](https://ideone.com/ZcT8Ys)

Comment: 1 - undefined behaviour; 2 - ok (because not every char array is a string); 3 - undefined behaviour

Comment: #1, Undefined behavior. Printf is looking for the trailing 0, its not there, it keeps going till it finds one (#3 too)

Answer (score 1):

1. `c2` is not a string, so passing it to `printf` `%s` has undefined behavior. Undefined behavior is undefined. Technically it isn't required to print anything. It could also delete all your files or go into an infinite loop or ...
2. Not all character arrays are strings. As long as you don't pass it to functions that expect a string, you can store whatever you want in your character array.
3. It has undefined behavior.

Comment: Ok I can forget thinking anything when it says undefined behavior. But I am still curious why `printf` is only printing `helloU` and `helloV`, I mean why just `U` and `V` and why always six characters? Why not more?

Comment: @anir That depends on the details of your platform/compiler. You'd have to look at the generated code, stack layout, etc.

Comment: **(1)** "`Not all character arrays are strings.`" How do you distinguish between them? Terminating with `\0` vs not terminating with `\0`? . **(2)** "`As long as you don't pass it to functions that expect a string, you can store whatever you want in your character array.`", do you mean that if you are not passing character array to function expecting string, you can forget to include `\0` in it, and it will still be fine?

Answer (score 1):

`printf` stops reading memory when it encounters a `\0`. In your example with `c2`, you do not know when `printf` is going to stop reading because you do not know where the next `\0` sits in memory. `printf` is indeed reading random memory, which explains why you can not predict what is going to be printed on screen. Eventually, you might start reading memory that does not belong to your program. If that happens, most operating systems will terminate your program immediately.

Think about this simple example:

```
int a;
printf("%d", a);
```

You can not predict what `a` will contain, and you therefore can not predict what will be printed on screens. The exact same thing happens in your example, you do not know what's after the `'o'` in your second array.

Comment: But then why `printf` is only printing `helloU` and `helloV`, I mean why just `U` and `V` why always six characters? Why not more?

Comment: This depends on how your debugger/OS might initialise memory. On my machine (macOS Mojave, Xcode 10), I get `hellohello`. The fact that this undefined behaviour **seems** to always follow a "pattern" does not make it less undefined. Try running your code [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler), you'll get something different.

Comment: Also, try swapping the declarations of `c1` and `c2`. This will change how the arrays are laid out in memory and probably change the output as well.